# append image tag into contenteditable div with jQuery

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

i have div with smiles and contenteditable div:

```
<div id="smiles">
    <img src="/img/smile/acute.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/aggressive.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/bad.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/biggrin.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/blum1.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/blush.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/boredom.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/bye.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/clapping.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/congratulate.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/cool.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/cray.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/dance.gif">
    <img src="/img/smile/dance2.gif">
</div>
<div contenteditable="false" unselectable="true" style="disabled:true" id="message_text">
    <img src="/img/smile/boredom.gif">
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
    $("#smiles").on('click', 'img', function () {
        if ($('#message_text').prop("contentEditable")) {
            $('#message_text').append($(this).clone()).focus();
        }
    });
```

also i'm trying

```
if ($('#message_text').attr("contentEditable"))
```

i want append smile if div is contentEditable but `IF` doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: if i make alert($('#message_text').prop("contentEditable")) i receive true or false, but if ($('#message_text').prop("contentEditable")) it always append it

Comment: if(true) or if(false) works, it returns true or false, but it doesn't work @KevinBowersox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $("#smiles img").click(function(){
    if ($('#message_text').attr("contentEditable")=="false")
{
       $('#message_text').append($(this));

        }
  });
```